# Earth Engine create user defined function with default parameters

Tags: google-earth-engine, parameters, function

I am creating a user based function that I will save in my repository for re-use later.  But I'm facing a problem with putting default values in my parameters.

```
var myFunction = function(number, power = 2){

return(ee.Number(a).pow(power);
}

print(myFunction(2);

print(myFunction(2,3);
```

The whole point is that most of the time I will want to square a number, but some time I may want to do another power.  When you run the above example, you get an unexpected token error.  Which is surely due to the "=" in the function definition.

How can I set default parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that easily using:
Besides, yo have some missing brackets and you will have to use number inside the function where you places a.

```
var myFunction = function(number, power){

if (power === undefined || power === null){var power = 2}

return ee.Number(number).pow(power);
}

print(myFunction(2));

print(myFunction(2,3));
```

Comment: Excellent! I was stuck in R mode, where the default values are placed in the brackets of the variable declarations.

Comment: it could be simpler using `power = power || 2` instead of `if (power === undefined || power === null){var power = 2}`, at least for checking `undefined` and `null`

Comment: what you mean is that if `power` is `undefinded` or `null` then it will always default to 2?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what it means, both approaches